# How to turn a proprietary stream into a Flux from spring webflux

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a custom event bus where I can subscribe a lambda like

```
 bus.subscribe(topic, event -> {/*gets executed for every new event*/}, exception -> {})
```

Now the lambda is obviously running in a different thread. Now my question is how can I connect this kind of interface to a `Flux<Event>`? do I have to write my own `Publisher`? But people say it's not a good idea to do so.

A mock implementation would be

```
import java.util.function.Consumer

class Mock extends Thread {
    Consumer<String> lambda

    public Mock(Consumer<String> lambda) {
        this.lambda = lambda
    }

    @Override
    void run() {
        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            lambda.accept("lala")
        }
    }
}

Flux<String> flux = new Mock({ /*TODO write to flux*/ }).start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re right, you should not implement your own publisher. In most cases, you should not have to deal with threads either and instead rely on static methods on `Flux`.

Something like:

```
Flux<Event> events = Flux.<Event>create(emitter -> {

     bus.subscribe(topic, event -> emitter.next(event),
         exc -> emitter.error(exc));

     // you should also unsubscribe
     emitter.onDispose(() -> {
         bus.unsubscribe(topic, ...);
     });
 });
```

Comment: whoohoo .. cool thx! PS I know we should avoid such comments but I am just very excited :-)